# MySQL: ORDER BY position in string of values

Tags: mysql

I would like to order my results in the order that they appear in a (very large) string. For the sake of this question, I've limited that string to 5 entries.

For example:

```
select * from table where value in ("banana","apple","pineapple","cherry","mango")
```

I would like to order those results by the order in which they appear in that string. Now obviously with just 5 results that's possible with CASE WHEN etc. but how about a much longer string (e.g. 1000 values) where that's just not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) with a slightly different query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE value IN ("banana","apple","pineapple","cherry","mango")
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(value, 'banana,apple,pineapple,cherry,mango')
```

> **`FIND_IN_SET(str, strlist)`**
>
> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by , characters. If the first
>   argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET,
>   the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns
>   0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns
>   NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly
>   if the first argument contains a comma (,) character.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
>     -> 2
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect - looks like I'd simply messed up the formatting of y string in the FIND_IN_SET argument. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you solve your problem!